# Optimizar reporte

Tags: php, html, excel, phpexcel, optimización

Estoy usando `php` con una `librería` algo vieja pero funciona solo con la versión de `php 7.0`

Al momento exportar informes en `excel` estos tienen mas  de 500.000 registros y demora mucho al generar el reporte.

¿Cómo puedo optimizar este proceso?

Comment: ¿Podrías dar más información sobre la librería?, Supongo que estás obteniendo la información desde una base de datos, ¿Estas usando índices?

Comment: Hola si claro que si, la toma de una tabla especial postgrest donde tiene toda la informacion, requerida para el informe la libreria que usamos es PHPExcel

  phpspreedsheet no la usamos por la version de la aplicacion y aun soy nuevo en esto

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usa `índices` en tu base de datos:

Realizaremos un pequeño ejemplo, vamos a suponer que tenemos un millón de usuarios en nuestra base de datos y queremos obtener los usuarios que tengan el rol_id 5, para ello vamos a ejecutar lo siguiente:

```
select * from usuarios where rol_id = 5 // Suponiendo que no tienen índice en el campo rol_id
```

Esto tardará demasiado en obtener esa información, para ello vamos a crear un índice para el compo rol_id

```
CREATE INDEX ON usuarios (rol_id);
```

También puedes asignarle un nombre a tu índice

```
CREATE INDEX usuarios_role_id ON usuarios USING btree (rol_id);
```

Comment: Hola muchas gracias,

lo que sucede y no se si tambien se pueda aplicar la tabla en la base de datos esta lelna filtramos por fechas , pero creo que tambien parte del problema es al exportalos crear el excel y pintar los datos para luego exportalos tarda, se puede optimizar eso tambien , teniendo encuenta que uno PHPEXCEL?

Comment: También puedes aplicar index a las fechas